# catching error of multiple http requests using concat

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

Able to catch error inside individual ajax requests using pipe operator, but how can i catch outside concat. getting error source.lift not a function. please point out where i am going wrong and what would be better option for serial requests.

```
export const deleteSettingsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('DELETE_SETTINGSDATA'),
    flatMap(action$ => concat(
        ajax.ajaxDelete(`${action$.payload.api}/${action$.payload.id}`)
            .pipe(
                map(r => ({ type: 'DELETE_SUCCESS' })),
                // catchError( e => of({type: 'DELETE_ERROR'}))
            ),
        ajax.get(`${action$.payload.api}`)
            .pipe(
                map(r => ({
                    type: action$.payload.getPaginationAction,
                    payload: {
                        leadSourceList: r.response.docs,
                        page: r.response.page,
                        totalPages: r.response.totalPages,
                        limit: r.response.limit,
                        totalDocs: r.response.totalDocs
                    }
                })),
                // catchError(e => of({type: 'FETCH_ERROR'}))
            ),        
            of({type: 'SET_DIMMER_FALSE'})
    ),
    catchError(e => of({type: 'FETCH_ERROR'}))
    ),
);
```

Comment: When i am placing catchError inside first pipe next to flatmap i am able to catch the error. Can someone explain whats going on, i am confused and i also want to delay 'SET_DIMMER_FALSE', Is there any better way? i need some clarity what's happening.  p.s started redux-observables 3 days back.

Comment: Resolved the issue. https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/601#issuecomment-455117791